# Thymeleaf namespace in html files display errors in Netbeans - How can I get it pass HTML checking?

Tags: java, html, netbeans, thymeleaf

Netbeans HTML checking doesn't like my thymeleaf namespace.

**Here is my HTML Thymleaf file**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <object th:include="fragments/meta :: meta" th:remove="tag" />

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700|Open+Sans:300italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

    <link href="/../../../webjars/Semantic-UI/2.0.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/Semantic-UI/2.0.6/semantic.min.css}"/> 
    <link href="../../../css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/core.css}" />
    <link href="../../../css/product.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/product.css}" />

    </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is the error displayed in Netbeans:**

[image]

How can I get Netbeans to play nicely with Thymeleaf?

Comment: Does it display errors in Eclipse? I am using `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">` without problems.

Comment: the adding of `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` worked for most of the errors but not for `<object th:include="fragments/meta :: meta" th:remove="tag" />`

Comment: Does it have to be `<object>`? There is something like `th:block` in Thymeleaf.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#bloc

Answer (score 10):

Try to fix it in this way you may ignore spring security thing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
          xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found out how to disable these errors when I was taking this [spring security tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

Simply by adding this to html tag:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

what's even cooler, netbeans now tracks if you closed every tag with slash "/" in document.